# how to detect nearest BLE 4.0 ios devices using corebluetooth?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I worked on detecting nearest BLE 4.0 ios devices using corebluetooth by referring this link 
http://olesitune.mine.nu/blelogg/?page_id=180
It's not detecting any ios device.can anyone provide some information regarding this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Are you using iOS 6? Only iOS 6 has support for setting the iOS device as server/peripheral. Remember that you can not discover any BLE devices from iOS just using the standard bluetooth settings, you have to write an app for both sides of the communication.

That guide will not help you discover any iOS devices, only standard BLE devices like heart rate monitors, temperatur sensors and such if you don't have an iOS6 device which is configured as a peripheral device.

I see that you have also posted this question elsewhere, but please submit some of your project code, results, debug data before expecting any helpful answers